# Class not displaying correctly

Tags: php

This is the code I am using to display a row in a table:

```
$msg.='<tr class="'.$outclass.'" onClick="popticket('.$ticket['TicketID'].');" onmouseover="this.className='.$overclass.';" onmouseout="this.className='.$outclass.';" '.$reg1.' '.$reg2.' >

      <td width="10%" align="center" class="style28" style="padding: 5px;">'.$ticket['TicketID'].'</td>
      <td width="25%" align="left" class="style28">'.substr($ticket['customer_bus_name'], 0, 34).'</td>
      <td width="12%" align="center" class="style28">'.$newpr.'</td>
      <td width="15%" align="center" class="style28">'.$status.'</td>
      <td class="style28">'.strip_tags($ticket['desc']).'</td>
      <td width="60px" align="center" class="style28"><span style="display:none;">'.$ticket['updated'].'</span>'.$new_up.'</td>
       <td width="45px" align="center" class="style28"><span style="display:none;">'.$ticket['scheduled'].'</span>'.$new_im.'</td>
      </tr>';
```

Here each PHP variable has its own value. The problem is that the class given in the `onmouseover` and `mouseout` is not working.

I want to get this row as (this is the correct output):

```
 <tr class="ticketrowsoutread" onmouseout="this.className='ticketrowsoutread';" onmouseover="this.className='ticketrowsover ticketrowsover2';" onclick="popticket('232');">
      <td width="10%" align="center" class="style28" style="padding: 5px;">232</td>
      <td width="25%" align="left" class="style28">net works</td>
      <td width="12%" align="center" class="style28">Medium</td>
      <td width="15%" align="center" class="style28">in progress</td>
      <td class="style28">adsfasdf</td>
      <td width="60px" align="center" class="style28"><span style="display:none;">1334709567</span>1 day</td>
      <td width="45px" align="center" class="style28"><span style="display:none;">-</span></td>
    </tr>
```

When I run my code it displays `onmouseout="this.className=ticketrowsoutread;"` instead of `onmouseout="this.className='ticketrowsoutread';"`.

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: For the hover styling, use the `:hover` CSS class!

Comment: please, stop attaching event in HTML

Comment: @tereško why are you insisting for that?may I know just for my knowledge?

Comment: @heyanshukla , maybe this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/CbC6L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add backslashes to escape the qote

```
onmouseover="this.className=\''.$overclass.'\';"
```

Comment: The simplest mistakes are the hardest ones to find, its always a good idea to let someone else take a look at. Or do something else for a moment and then look again.